# C# MVC MvcHtmlString TModel with checking if is null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
@Html.DisplayRowForWithDisplayName(model => model.CustomerDetail.IfNotNullReturnDefault(x => x.Id))
```

Extension method:

```
 public static TResult IfNotNullReturnDefault<TSource, TResult>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> function)
            where TSource : class
            where TResult : struct
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                return default(TResult);
            }
```

MVC builder

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayRowForWithDisplayName<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var model = metaData.Model;
                var displayName = metaData.DisplayName;
...
```

but I get exception here:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression[TParameter,TValue](Expression`1 expression, ViewDataDictionary`1 viewData, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression[TParameter,TValue](Expression`1 expression, ViewDataDictionary`1 viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.DisplayRowForWithDisplayName[TModel,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) in ...
```

How to heck if is not null in MVC?

Comment: The lambda expression you are passing to `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression` is a function call (MethodCallExpression) and not a direct access to a property, field or indexer (as the error message state). I believe you should change `DisplayRowForWithDisplayName` to have a third parameter for the value coalescing (like a  `Func<T, T>` that could fallback to an identity function) and leave the second parameter as a vanilla member access expression.

Comment: @Simon good idea, can you give me maybe an example of your idea?